# indexPath not updated after using deleteRowsAtIndexPaths

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I created a method which updates my UITableView when the user wants to delete a cell.

```
-(void)removeMoreFriendsRow:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSDictionary *d = [notification userInfo];
NSIndexPath *index = [d objectForKey:@"indexPath"];
    
[self.p_currentFriends removeObjectAtIndex:index.row];
    
[self.o_table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
}
```

p_currentFriends is a NSMutableArray which contains all the objects printed by the UITableView.

This method works fine when I use it once, but it fails when I use it more than once.

It appears that the indexPath stay the same at each call of deleteRowsAtIndexPaths.

For example,

- at the first call, the user taps on the second cell, indexPath = [0,1] and the correct cell is deleted,
- at the second call, the user taps on the third cell and indexPath = [0,3] instead of [0,2]

The only way I found to make it works is to use reloadData but I want to have a animation on the cell deletion.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is `p_currentFriends` really a dictionary or an array?

Comment: Sorry it's not a NSDictionary but a NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're doing is basically correct, but you'll need to reload the `tableView` somehow. If you don't want to reload the whole `tableView`, use this, which gives you an `animation` as well -

```
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionNum];
[self.o_table reloadSections:indexSet 
            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 5):

> **Swift 2.2**

The best solution I found is to set an `NSTimer` and call the reload data 0.5 sec after, which gives enough time for the animation to finish. The `Selector("loadData")` is a method that contains  `tableview.reloadData()`

```
_ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: Selector("loadData"), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

> **Swift 3.0**

```
_ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.loadData), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `reloadSections:` method works but it doesn't give you the normal animation for deleting a row, instead using a fade animation. In iOS 11 a new method is available which solves this:

```
  [tableView performBatchUpdates:^(
  {
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
  }
             completion:^(BOOL finished)
  {
    if( finished){ 
      [tableView reloadData];
  }
  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should surround delteRowsAtIndexPaths: and other table editing operations with [beginUpdates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [endUpdates](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).  That may resolve your issue.

Comment: Here is what I tried but it doesn't works. `[self.o_table beginUpdates];
    [self.o_table deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    [self.o_table endUpdates];``

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the above answer,Here is my solution:

```
- (void)deleteRowAtIndex:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    [self.dataSource.datas removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
    //    NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:indexPath.section];
    //    [self.tableView reloadSections:indexSet
    //                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    //    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    NSLog(@"INDEXPATH:%@",indexPath);
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5 target:self.tableView selector:@selector(reloadData) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the following code, I am able to do it correctly but I have to manage it separately for versions **before iOS 11** and **from iOS 11**.

See following example:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) { // indexPath is your needed indexPath

    [self->chatTableVC.messagesTable performBatchUpdates:^{
    [self->chatTableVC.messagesTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         [self->chatTableVC.messagesTable reloadData];
    }];

} else {

    [self->chatTableVC.messagesTable beginUpdates];
    [self->chatTableVC.messagesTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self->chatTableVC.messagesTable endUpdates];

}
```